# MongoDB Status: Degraded

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, discord.js

I'm currently having issues connecting to my database with mongoose. The status is degraded and I can't browse through my collections. I have no idea how this happened nor how to fix it. Any help is apprecriated.

[image]

Comment: Can you connect by some other means, e.g., `Compass` or `mongosh`?

Comment: hi did u resolve this issue later?

Comment: I am getting this issue now

Answer (score 1):

I saw the same thing on my free Atlas cluster and it simply resolved itself after a few minutes (which is what the UI indicated as well). It's frustrating as I hadn't changed anything and there was nothing I could do but wait.

Comment: true, it disappeared after few minutes, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had to wait for 3 mins. After that, the status changed itself. Keep waiting for a few minutes and refresh the page.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).